Getting error after trying to use authentication of Firebase service from another component
I am using the Firebase Authentication service in my Angular app. I have created a service to check the user authentication status. When I try to use this as a service in the navbar component I get this error every time. What to do now?
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

    at node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\@angular_fire_auth.js:5659:36)
    at __require2 (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LI6NGK76.js:49:50)
    at node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\@angular_fire_auth.js:5851:9)
    at __require2 (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LI6NGK76.js:49:50)
    at node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\@angular_fire_auth.js:6027:9)
    at __require2 (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LI6NGK76.js:49:50)
    at node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\@angular_fire_auth.js:13914:9)
    at __require2 (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LI6NGK76.js:49:50)
    at node_modules/undici/index.js (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\@angular_fire_auth.js:19829:33)
    at __require2 (C:\Users\Dell\Code\Angular\code-bin\.angular\cache\18.2.1\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LI6NGK76.js:49:50


Authentication Service using Firebase
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }

  isUserSignIn() {
    return this.auth.currentUser != null ? true : false;
  }

}

Navbar Component
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink, RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { AuthService } from '../../service/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, NgClass],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.css'
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  isUserSignIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
    this.isUserSignIn = this.authService.isUserSignIn();
  }
}



Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces this problem it is unlikely that anyone can meaningfully help beyond what a quick search of the error message already does.

Update the code causing error @puf-FrankvanPuffelen
